# How to deploy and run an asp.net mvc 6 web api project in azure using git

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to deploy a simple mvc 6 web api project in azure and am having trouble.

I've crated the basic getting started example api http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-web-api.html and pointed my azure web application resource to my git repository.

I see that the git push triggers a deployment, the app is running, but I get a 404 response when I make a request.

The event viewer shows an event `Engine state is changed from Available to Stopped.`

FREB logs shows 
`OUTPUT_CACHE_LOOKUP_END    Result="NOT_FOUND"`

How can I diagnose and what is the correct way to deploy mvc 6 apps on azure using git?

Comment: Did you implement the deployment from the [github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/mvc/getting-started/first-web-api/sample) or did you create your own repo based on the documentation? If so, is this repo public?

Comment: not sure what the question is, I configured azure to look at the git repo - and the permission are correct on the repo hook and azure sees the repo changes.

Comment: I meant that if the repo is yours or you targeted the example repo. If the repo is yours, is it public? Can I try to hook it from my Azure Web App and debug the deployment?

Comment: yup, it's public: https://github.com/mypark/mvc6demo feel free to give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

I [forked your repo](https://github.com/ealsur/mvc6demo) and deployed it to a Standard Web App (not Free since RC1 has a size problem and can't be deployed to Free Web Apps)on: http://myparkmvc6demost.azurewebsites.net/

Since your project is a WebApi, the correct way of accessing it is: http://myparkmvc6demost.azurewebsites.net/api/todo

This is defined in your [TodoController](https://github.com/ealsur/mvc6demo/blob/master/Controllers/TodoController.cs):

```
namespace ttg_api.Controllers
{  
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TodoController : Controller
    {
        [FromServices]
        public ITodoRepository TodoItems { get; set; }

        // GET: api/todo
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<TodoItem> GetAll()
        {
            return TodoItems.GetAll();
        }

//more code....
}
```

You won't find anything if your browse the root of the site, this is not an Mvc "Website" by the normal understanding, it's using MVC6 to create a WebApi because that's the way in ASPNET5.

Comment: I wasn't going to the root url, I was sending reqeusts to the api endpoints as mentioned... it started working after I forced a re-synchornization and a new commit.  Not sure why it started working when it didn't work before..

Comment: Not sure then what could be the problem, are you hosting many Web Apps on that same App Service? Could it be a resource consumption problem?

Comment: only a single app, single app service

Comment: Beats me then, I couldn't repro it with the same repo code, the API works like it should.

Comment: hmm yeah not sure what the issue was for me either... maybe an azure hiccup?  I'll close this question for now until I can repro again.